# Взаимодействие переменных и вычисляемых переменные

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

При изменении вычисляемой переменной `nown` изменяется переменная `beginDate`.

Почему так?

[CodeSabdbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6x4j69j55n)

```
<template>
<div>
    <datepicker v-model="beginDate" v-bind:disabled="nowd" format="MM/dd/yyyy"></datepicker>  
    <datepicker :value.sync="nown.to" v-bind:disabled="nown" format="MM/dd/yyyy"></datepicker>
</div>    
</template>

<script>
import Datepicker from "vuejs-datepicker";

export default {
  name: "form",
  components: {
    Datepicker
  },
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "Form",
      beginDate: new Date()
    };
  },
  computed: {
    nowd: function() {
      let currentDate = new Date();
      currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 1);
      return { to: currentDate };
    },
    nown: function() {
      let currentDate = this.beginDate;
      currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 14);
      return { to: currentDate };
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это потому что вы используете присваивание

```
let currentDate = this.beginDate;
```

Поскольку значением является объект, то копируется ссылка а не значение. Вам надо клонировать объект для создания нового объекта, который будет использоваться другим пикером даты.

Comment: спс, я точно понял, что пора спать, ибо такие глупые ошибки не замечаю)